# How to manipulate JavaScript code together with its sourcemap (in node.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, source-maps

We have some JavaScript that is output generated by a compiler that also created a source-map.

Now I'd like to do some simple work on this output JS like adding some lines or stripping some code. But it has to be done in a way that would also update the source-map so it stays valid for the changed code.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why can't you edit the original code?

Comment: the desired changes cannot be expressed with the original language or toolchain (which is why I want to post-process).

Comment: OK, I see. Still, even if not relevant for the question, I'm curious what compiler you are using and what parts of the output code you need to manipulate?

Comment: In my practical case I use TypeScript and want to do all kinds of creative stuff with the JS output. Like concatenating files, splicing substrings etc.

Comment: So you don't want to modify what the code does, but only move parts of it around? You might want to have a look at [Generating source maps for multiple concatenated javascript files](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15964826/1048572) then.

Comment: Thanks, those cover a fair chunk of what I would do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to work on the source code, or you will have to generate a new sourcemap from the new one.