# Get Chrome stack trace of error object relative to sourceURL

Tags: google-chrome, coffeescript, google-chrome-devtools, browserify, source-maps

When using Chrome I am getting an error via the Mocha test runner, captured as part of `afterEach` with `this.currentTest.err`.

I am compiling coffeescript with browserify with the debug option using the awesome coffeeify plugin. This produces a single compiled file `bundle.js` with a `sourceMappingURL=data:...` that allows me to view and debug the original coffeescript directly.

Unfortunately when I access the `err.stack` in the `afterEach` Mocha hook, the stack contains references to `bundle.js` and not the corresponding `.coffee` files, which would be much more useful.

Here is some sample code with browserify.

First, installing it (for convenience) with npm:

```
$ npm install -g browserify; npm install coffeeify
```

#### x.coffee

```
try
  throw Error("Thrown.")
catch err
  console.log err.stack
```

Convert to `x.js` with:

```
$ browserify -t coffeeify x.coffee -d > x.js
```

#### x.html

```
<html>
 <head>
   <script src='x.js'></script>
 </head>
 <body></body>
</html>
```

If one opens this in Chrome the dev tools will show `x.js`, `x.coffee` (from the `sourceMapURL`) and `x.html`.

When we run this HTML page we get the following output to the `console`:

```
Error: Thrown.
    at Error ()
    at Object. (file://localhost/Users/bmh/tmp/x.js:5:9)
    at i (file://localhost/Users/bmh/tmp/x.js:1:219)
    at err (file://localhost/Users/bmh/x.js:1:382)
    at file://localhost/Users/bmh/tmp/x.js:1:400
```

What we would expect is to have the trace refer to the `.coffee` file, looking something like this (which I am making up here for illustrative purposes):

```
Error: Thrown.
    at Error ()
    at Object. (file://localhost/Users/bmh/tmp/x.coffee:2:5)
```

Has anyone had any success converting the error stack to one that refers to the items at their source map locations?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15419813/source-mapping-in-coffeescript-errors-not-mapped-to-source

Comment: Thanks @jcollum - the issue is similar. The problem here is that a caught `err.stack` does not contain the mapped line and source references. When an untaught error is printed to the console the line numbers are mapped correctly (as per the link you provided).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about coffeeify, but the [source-map-support](https://github.com/evanw/node-source-map-support) module adds `.stack` support for code bundled with browserify. Just `npm install source-map-support` and put `require('source-map-support').install()` at the top of your code.